# Weird encoding in 8-bit binary file

Tags: file, encoding, character-encoding, binary, output

I am trying to write 8-bit data (specifically, integers ranging from 0 to 256) to an 8-bit binary file. Apparently, this can mean a lot of different things.

To me, this meant I should just output numbers 0-256 to a file and save it as ".bin". E.g.: 12, 31, 52, 34, etc.

However, when I look at the example file for the function I am using, the encoding is something like this:

```
$D´/êÌ4¹äæ¸à©+%+
ü§Ö¾ZýDƒöDÛW.©òŒ¡¤¤ÝÎ¹õ¬>Ž€R˜ZêO3»'OtB A¡…ÛÜWŒôðÉ£«AŠÓ¡m7?Yu![%øËÑÔOƒ»$4‚yÌlm7Û÷(Ó2'h&^Îc¦ý£Ê)C­u!ýú}|“ï˜¤Fi    fgfôõ†Aó›   sÇ;ÁFlä½À‰Z« >2¢*ÚyÓ©’¨¿ì-Ÿ1Ê6‰>çŸÃÄ±²(€Ó?PãwG‚k©Þ¨<äÎ5ÚHç~—ƒ÷û‡ì™¦œÆ`–­n¯Ó
AüÄ †ný^D`ÜúYD'Ãñì4ß%KÚz| ±¢m/ð±ð‡ƒ–Xm ‰;2®d’+@á¤DtïšÆ¯+Ÿ“,XCg"s>CÅí1JíšÚlÌóüªí
÷Eª´ÜW¤æŽYÄãw‘IÃuÐç’ÈyX”22é[f2ÀCƒ*  e|Ë›:áæ²€´µ‰ûcÇz(¡‰ýY#rWÖ8BjnKó@ýx´l$WÂX[¦,ä3÷òiabi¾2eó¾Ù[ŽOfB”÷FIÈJög¹æO°¼qÖüè×TáQÿYªqãˆ
Vh=eN¦Sœ ãÓšÇ
‡WÜÀìé:”lýT]˜ÇIübjüYµÕE¨¹nÓé‰Šñañ—(hrû6YÈÐ³-a‚™A_LnŸË˜jAì“Æ€(9Èã·âÁzW’d°ß¢Ä1ŸôˆUÀ&Ú:ÐÂk³}ø/râ."¤ƒ:¡WÙŠ€¥â„´Ý¯nõoWDÉ¨®¸áÅzø !ú•g‰\òL¡-í¦°nBÖÂlÒÚëžÆlºNz[àŠ»–Àé1ó6©Â¼¹æö·œ¹#
“ÍìqåŸW¤ª
*‘=_.‰^4{@»@Ã{µÕ³`
```

My question is, how can I convert a list of 8-bit integers into whatever file-type is specified above?

Edit:
To be clearer, I have already written these integers to a ".bin" file, and my file is perfectly human-readable. But, the function requires the input to be in the non-human-readable format I've shown above. How do I convert my human-readable numbers into the non-human-readable format above?

Comment: That looks about like what I'd expect to see if you opened a random stream of bytes in a text editor.  What were you expecting?

Comment: A "binary" file does not necessarily contain only printable characters.  When you attempt to print a binary file as character data you get garbage.  You need to use a "hex editor" (such as [HDD Hex Editor Neo](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor)) to display the data in hex.

Comment: You can use the editor binary, for example http://www.pspad.com/en/faq.htm

Comment: And i am paypal-ing $20 to any and all who can write out a 256 8-bit binary

Comment: I am confused by these answers. I have integers that I need to convert to that weird encoding so that they can be used as an input to a python function. Any suggestions? Will a hex() function work?

Comment: I edited my question above that will probably be clearer now

Answer (score -1):

Who says you are doing it wrong at all. I am being serious. Who said it is going to be naturally readable by your average human?

Comment: The python function I am using will not accept simple integers? It needs the weird encoding.... How do I convert the simple integers to the encoding?

Comment: Are you asking or telling not sure what you mean. You have a number decimal to you like 7 or 193. When you write out binary data it is stored in not exactly human readable form

Comment: Download a hex editor online then let's chat as you seem new to this

Comment: I wrote the data in a human-readable format, but the function I am using will not accept it in human-readable format. The example input to the function (included by the function's developer) has the weird encoding listed above. I am trying to convert my data (human-readable) into the weird encoding above.

Comment: I downloaded a hex editor and that did help me ~understand~ the problem, but I am still not sure how to solve my particular problem

Comment: You write out 3 bytes for a test. Here are the numbers (19)(115)(207). If they are written out in binary format with 1 Byte each they will appear as (13)(73)(CF) when you point the hex editor program at your output file

Comment: Yo why is this so hard for me? Every internet resource is about writing numbers in 0111000 but not in this alternate binary format you talk about

Comment: I don't know what you mean or even know if you still need help. I gave you a 3 byte example above. Maybe you are all set. Maybe you need me to say 19D = 13H = 00010011B (dec hex bin respectfully).

Comment: It is hex and you have a hex editor. Hex to binary is easy in a programmers head as they are just base-2 but slighly different.

Comment: And because data is written to files in bytes (that is hex) and not in bit chunks (that is binary) it is a no brainer for someone knowing what they are doing